# custom jquery mobile icons navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get custom jQuery mobile navbar icons and it's not working.  I know the question has been asked before and I think I am doing it right can someone look at my code and see if they can see the problem please.

```
.ui-icon-directions {
background-image:url("http://c9.io/mbochicchio/tradingpost/workspace/img/mobilephotos/directions.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: 20px 20px;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
margin: 0 !important;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/ragingnomad/NHC9p/5/

Comment: If you know it has been asked before, what makes you believe that the solutions given there don't work for you? If there were no solutions, what makes you thing they will be forthcoming now?

Comment: I tried the solutions that others have provided and they weren't working.  Thanks to ezanker, his fix for JQM 1.4.x worked.

Answer (score 1):

In jQM 1.4.x, background image is applied to the :after pseudo-selector:

```
.ui-icon-directions:after {
    background-image:url("http://c9.io/mbochicchio/tradingpost/workspace/img/mobilephotos/directions.png");

}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/NHC9p/6/)**

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked!  JQM needs to update the documentation on their site for v1.4.x because I didn't see any mention of the :after pseudo-selector on there.